# How to load google font only if custom logo is not uploaded

Tags: logo, fonts

How can I load Google font only if custom logo is not uploaded?

I know how to load resource if we are on this or that page, but not sure how to do this?

Comment: Are you, or your theme, using `add_theme_support( 'custom-logo' )` to allow custom logos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function for this purpose, called [`has_custom_logo()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_custom_logo/). You can check whether the website has a custom logo or not by having this conditional:

```
if ( ! has_custom_logo() ) {
    // Enqueue some google fonts
    wp_enqueue_style( 'google-fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Didn't know that I can use has_custom_logo() inside functions.php, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The code is not tested but is a good starting point, you may need to add action to enqueue the css or you can write a functions and add the code below into it.

```
  // Enable Custom Logo
      add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
          'height'      => 200,
          'width'       => 400,
          'flex-width' => true,
      ) );

    $old_logo = get_theme_mod( 'header_logo' );
    if ( $old_logo ) {

      wp_enqueue_style( 'wpse_89494_style_3', get_template_directory_uri() . '/your-style_3.css' );

    }
```